# exec(foo | at now) in PHP script

Tags: php, command, exec

I'm currently trying to execute in a PHP script a command using exec(), but delayed in time.

I tried :

```
exec('at now | fooCommand >> aLog.log 2>&1');
```

Does not work and :

```
exec('fooCommand >> aLog.log 2>&1 | at now');
```

Neither. However :

```
exec('echo "fooCommand >> aLog.log 2>&1" | at now"');
```

Works but seems to launch only the echo command, not the desired fooCommand.

Any ideas how to write this correcty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, after a lot of searching :

```
exec('echo "fooCommand >> aLog.log 2>&1" | at now + 2 hours');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are delaying your script, I think it would be more beneficial to use sleep instead of at (at can only use minutes and up, no seconds).

Is fooCommand a variable? If so, try your middle solution but replace your single quotations with double quotations.

```
exec("fooCommand >> aLog.log 2>&1 | at now");
```

In PHP, variables are ignored when you enclose them in single quotations.

Comment: In fact, it does not work correctly with :
`exec("fooCommand >> aLog.log 2>&1 | at now + " . $i . " hour");`
with i an integer (3 for instance). The script is run with no delay

Comment: Try hours instead of hour.

Comment: That does not solve the problem either, the script is run instantly.
The complete srcipt is :
`$randH = rand(0, 27);
exec("php ../app/console command:async dBot -- " . $square->getId() . " >> ../dBot.log 2>&1 | at now + " . ($randH+3) . " hours");`

Comment: If you run that command manually via the terminal, does it work? This could be an issue with the "at" command rather than PHP.

Comment: `exec('echo "fooCommand >> aLog.log 2>&1" | at now + 2 hours');` worked